# find word that each character separated by space

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I need a *regex* to select a *word* that *each char* on that word *separated by whitespace*. Look at the following string

```
Mengkapan,Sungai Apit,S I A K,Riau,
```

I want to select `S I A K`. I am stuck, I was trying to use the following regex

```
\s+\w{1}\s+
```

but it's not working.

Comment: `\b[A-Za-z](?:\s+[A-Za-z])+\b`

Comment: awesome..thank you @DmitryBychenko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest

```
\b[A-Za-z](?:\s+[A-Za-z])+\b
```

pattern, where

```
\b           - word boundary
[A-Za-z]     - letter (exactly one)
(?:          - one or more groups of  
   \s+       - white space (at least one)
   [A-Za-z]  - letter (exactly one)
)+
\b           - word boundary
```

Comment: all anwsers from people on SO are working perfectly, but Dmitry answer's deserved to be accepted answer because he's the first to comment. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

For your given information, you could use

```
(?:[A-Za-z] ){2,}[A-Za-z]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/2XOiYi/1/).

Comment: Counter example? `"As I Say"` will return match `"s I S"`

Answer (score 2):

You could match a word boundary `\b`, a word character `\w` and repeat at least 2 times a space and a word character followed by a word boundary:

`\b\w(?: \w){2,}\b`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i3PZNg/1/)

Comment: Counter example? `"As I Say"` will return match `"s I S"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Sharp! You are right, I have added word boundaries.